# Deconstruct view model into table structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a view model which consists of data that has been flatten in order to populate a Pivot Grid.

This works fine however now I need a way to write values back to the database entity.

The entity has 3 composite properties, which make each row unique, JobLevelId, GenderId, RaceId.

The data hydrated into the view model is grouped by the JobLevel.

I need to find a way to deconstruct the view model and not sure the best way to do this e.g. if MaleAfrican has a value of 30, then this would need to be saved in the database as

```
new EmploymentValue{ JobLevelId = 1, GenderId = 1, Race = 1, Value = 30 }
```

**Lookup Tables:**

**Job Levels**

```
| ID | Description |
| -- | ----------- |
| 1  | Senior      |
| 2  | Mid         |
| 3  | Junior      |
```

**Gender**

```
| ID | Description |
| -- | ----------- |
| 1  | Male        |
| 2  | Female      |
| 3  | Other       |
```

**Race**

```
| ID | Description |
| -- | ----------- |
| 1  | Blue        |
| 2  | Red         |
| 3  | Green       |
```

**View Model:**

```
public class EmploymentValueViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id => Guid.NewGuid();
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }
        public int MaleBlue { get; set; }
        public int MaleRed { get; set; }
        public int MaleGreen { get; set; }
        public int FemaleBlue { get; set; }
        public int FemaleRed { get; set; }
        public int FemaleGreen { get; set; }
        public int OtherBlue { get; set; }
        public int OtherRed { get; set; }
        public int OtherGreen { get; set; }
    }
```

**Database Entity:**

```
[Table("EmploymentValues")]
    public class EmploymentValue
    {
        [Required]
        [Column("fkJobLevelID", Order = 1)]
        public int? JobLevelId { get; set; }

        public virtual JobLevel OccupationalLevel { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("fkRaceID", Order = 2)]
        public int RaceId { get; set; }

        public virtual Race Race { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("fkGenderID", Order = 3)]
        public int GenderId { get; set; }

        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: _I need to find a way to deconstruct the view model and not sure the best way to do this e.g. if MaleAfrican has a value of 30, then this would need to be saved in the database as `new EmploymentValue{ JobLevelId = 1, GenderId = 1, Race = 1 }  `_ - can you explain this a bit more? How does 30 end out as those values?

Comment: @stuartd This is just trying to demonstrate the values that will be stored on the entity. new EmploymentValue{ JobLevelId = 1, GenderId = 1, Race = 1, Value = 30 }